# Javascript modal opens every image on page, but I don't want it to

Tags: javascript

Okay, so I have this script:

```
<script>
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

span.onclick = function() { 
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
   images[i].onclick = function(){
       modal.style.display = "block";
       modalImg.src = this.src;
       modalImg.alt = this.alt;
       captionText.innerHTML = this.nextElementSibling.innerHTML;
   }
}
</script>
```

I am new to Javascript and what I am trying to do is to make a gallery, and I did really, but now the modal is applied to every single image I have on that page. The modal is supposed to enlarge image when clicked.

Comment: Narrow down your selection with a class name.

Comment: How can you differentiate those images with other images ? `getElementsByTagName('img')` will give you all the images in the document.

Comment: You could use [getElementsByClassName](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp).

Comment: What everybody is saying is 1) add `class="gallery-item"` to your gallery `img` elements, and 2) change `var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');` to `var images = document.getElementsByClassName('gallery-item');`

Comment: I have done that already. It works, but then when I click the image, the image isn't displaying. It displays the image in thumbnail, and when I click it, it opens modal and the image' border, but not the actual image.

Comment: I managed to do that, I just added class="gallery-item" and it works. Thank you guys! @NikolayErmakov